# create receipt for IR-ISO process in Oracle apps r12

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper, oracle-apps, plsql-package

After internal sales order created, I want to receive that material through backend means to create receipt after delivery number generated.

I have tried this: First insert the data into `rcv_header_interface`,then into `rcv_transaction_interface` then using Receiving Transaction Processor standard program, but it doesn't work.

I am using oracleapps version r12 12.2.4.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. _Specifically_, what does "doesn't work" mean?